# synchronized Listview Scrolling

Tags: java, listview, javafx, scrollbar

I have two adjacent scrollbars. I need to synchronize their scrolling so they move vertically together. The ListView on the left will most likely have more items than the ListView on the right. I need the left-hand ListView to scroll all the way down. I attempted to use the code:

```
    Node n1 = listView1.lookup(".scroll-bar");
    if (n1 instanceof ScrollBar) {
        final ScrollBar bar1 = (ScrollBar) n1;
        Node n2 = listView2.lookup(".scroll-bar");
        if (n2 instanceof ScrollBar) {
            final ScrollBar bar2 = (ScrollBar) n2;
            bar1.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(bar2.valueProperty());
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't seem to work, mainly because it does not pick up that n1 is an instance of ScrollBar and n1 is set to NULL. I'm not sure why the lookup function is not setting a node value.

Here are a list of the imports I am using:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;    
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When are you trying to do the lookup? Lookups generally only work once CSS has been applied, which is typically after the scene has been rendered.

Comment: in the initalize section of the scene is this why it is not working?

Comment: Yes, probably. Try calling `applyCss()` on the root of the scene before trying the lookup. You may need to do something more sophisticated though.

Comment: So this does seem to be the problem, if I call the look up from a different location it does work. However, I do need this look up to be made in the Initialize. could you explain how to call the applyCss() on the root. or another workaround. I tried applying the CSS to the listviews and this did not seem to work.

Comment: Did you try just calling `applyCss()` on the root element of the FXML? Just inject the root element (if you're not doing already) and call `rootElement.applyCss();`.

Comment: I tried this. The root element in this case was an anchor pane. at this point in time none of the elements are using CSS files as I have not stylized any of the program yet. is there another way to call code similar to a main method after the Initialize function has finished?

Comment: That shouldn't matter in terms of making the lookup work, I think. The other, (even?) more hacky workaround is to register a listener with the `sceneProperty()` of the list view(s) and do the lookup when the scene changes to non-null.

Comment: Is there perhaps just a better way to make the scroll bars synch? Perhaps I could build this functionality into the CSS or there is a better way to gain this functionality. it seems strange to me that Oracle would make it so difficult to build in this type of functionality.

Comment: Well, not that I know of. In fact, I'm not actually convinced even this will work, even if you manage to lookup the scroll bars. You might want to have a look at Tomas Mikula's [Flowless](https://github.com/TomasMikula/Flowless) API, which I think will give you more of the API you need for this. It is something of a gap in the API.

Comment: thank you for all your help james

Comment: this is horrible but I'm just going to call the code every time the scroll starts this will minimize the code calling and make sure that it is called before the scroll happens